# Auto-implemented properties with non null guard clause?

Tags: c#, code-contracts, automatic-properties, guard-clause

I do agree with Mark Seeman's notion that [Automatic Properties are somewhat evil](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/26/CodeSmellAutomaticProperty.aspx) as they break encapsulation. However I do like the concise syntax, readability and convenience they bring.

I quote:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

> The problem with the code snippet isn’t that it contains too much
>   ceremony. The problem is that it breaks encapsulation. In fact
>
> “[…] getters and setters do not achieve encapsulation or information
>   hiding: they are a language-legitimized way to violate them.”
>
> James O. Coplien & Gertrud Bjørnvig. Lean Architecture. Wiley. 2010. p. 134.

Most of the time, adding a non-null guard clause is good enough for a property setter and I would like to know if there is a better way of doing it than one of the below. By better, I mean in a more concise/less repetitive way.

Using Code Contracts:

```
private string _username;
public virtual string Username
{
    get { return _username; }
    set 
    {  
        Contract.Requires(value != null);
        _username = value; 
    }
}
```

Using vanilla .NET:

```
private string _username;
public virtual string Username
{
    get { return _username; }
    set 
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Username");
        _username = value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: don't think it's possible, honestly. But curiose to listen someone else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll just quote the [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) manual, § 2.3.1:

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set ; }

[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant () 
{
      Contract. Invariant ( this.MyProperty >= 0 );
      ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the closest to what I am looking for, even though less than optimal as it will be run on every single getter/setter..

Answer (score 3):

You could use aspects from PostSharp to decorate the property setter with a null check:

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/5-Ways-That-Postsharp-Can-SOLIDify-Your-Code-Lazy-Loading-of-Dependencies.aspx

[How to create an aspect checking for null references on all methods in a class in postsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261151/how-to-create-an-aspect-checking-for-null-references-on-all-methods-in-a-class-in)

http://magpie.sytes.net/jesperhogstrom/2010/11/compiler-safe-null-checking-of-arguments-with-aspects/

Comment: I was sensing that PostSharp would come up. I wonder how much performance hit you would get doing the same with Castle Interceptors and a custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume properties are just memory buffer from user point of view. only when a method (action) is invoke in user code, then checks on validity of the properties buffer should be checked (e.g., null checks throws exception).

your properties setter should place an invalid value to the internal member if data assigned is not valid (in your algorithm design). the error check and return should come from the method using this property value

Comment: I agree with this, I tend not to validate on entry to a property - but validate when that property is used.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't really agree with this, as it's against the "fail fast" principle which I am a believer of.

Comment: @Can I tend to disregard that for anything that isn't UI stuff.  Especially with property-based classes, such as with Xaml things.  Property validity could relate to the content of another property, which could be as yet un-set.

Comment: @Adam, I think for DTOs this is ok, but for domain objects encapsulation and validation of state are very important.

Comment: @Can I didn't say they weren't.  Not validating on set into a property doesn't break that, so long as it's done later.

Comment: @Can, your approach, from my point, is strictly dictated by your program design, I mean, what properties are used for. In my design style, properties are replacing method parameters and it allows me to put more logic into the parameter "transfer" mechanism, e.g., parse a string. setting the value should never fail. but i do see your point as well, just i have no experience and never used this approach